# Diffeomorphism-invariant spaces of smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, invariant-theory

Let's start with an interesting story. In his celebrated *Partial Differential Relations* (p. 146), the great Misha Gromov gives a nice exercise of which the following is a (strict) part.

**Exercise.** Consider the action of $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb R^n)$  on the space $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ of smooth functions $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. Then

- if $n\geq 2$, then there are exactly six (non-trivial) invariant subspaces;
- if $n = 1$, then there are ten of them.

It's quite easy to find the invariant subspaces Gromov is thinking about (I will give no spoiler...). The problem is that, according to [these](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=253&threadID=560649&messageID=1679714#1679714) two [messages](http://web.archive.org/web/20131005215609/http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/96/diffeo_invar) of C. McMullen, **the exercise is actually false.**

McMullen's counterexample is the following: take a sequence space $S \subset \mathbb R^\mathbb N$ and define the function subspace
$$\mathscr E[S] = \left\{ f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R) \,\middle|\, \forall (x_n)_n \in \mathbb R^\mathbb N, |x_n| \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty \Longrightarrow (f(x_n))_n \in S\right\}.$$
This is quite clearly a $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb R)$-invariant subspace of $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$. McMullen claims that the sequence space
$$\mathrm{bv} = \left\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\,\middle |\, \sum_{k} |a_{k+1} - a_k| < +\infty \right\}$$
already gives an example of an "exotic" invariant subspace $\mathscr E[\mathrm{bv}]$ (i.e. one different from Gromov's ten examples) and that it is easy to modify it to give **uncountably many** such invariant subspaces.

I have two questions:

1. Can you prove McMullen's claims?
2. If $n\geq 2$, is there an invariant subspace which isn't of the form $\mathscr E[S]$? (if $n = 1$, the space $\mathscr E[S]$ doesn't make any difference between the two ends $\pm \infty$ of $\mathbb R$ so only six of Gromov's ten subspaces are of this form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I left the original answer below, but I think the sequence space $\mathcal{E}[bv]$ as defined in the question and its variation defined below is just the space of functions which are constant in some neighborhood of $\infty$, and I assume that this is one of the "standard" spaces Gromov mentions. Just to clarify, I used $m$ as an index since $n$ is used for the dimension of the space.

If a function $f$ is not constant in some neighborhood of $\infty$, there exists a sequence of points $y_k \to \infty$ such that $f(y_k) \ne f(y_l)$ for $k \ne l$. Now pick integers $N_k > 1/|f(y_k) - f(y_{k+1})|$, and define the sequence $(x_m)$ by concatenating $N_1$ pairs $y_1, y_2$, then $N_2$ pairs $y_2, y_3$, in general $N_k$ pairs $y_k, y_{k+1}$. By the choice of integers, the variation in the sequence $f(x_m)$ over the $N_k$ pairs $f(y_k), f(y_{k+1})$ is greater than 1 for every $k$, so the total variation is infinite.

In the case $n=1$ one could modify the definition and restrict it to monotone sequences $(x_m)$, in which case the spaces of finite $p$-variation are all distinct, which can be shown using functions of the form $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha}$ for $x \ge 1$. However, I see no similar modification which would work in dimension greater than 1.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER: I don't know the answer to the second question, but for the first part it seems that replacing finite variation by finite $p$-variation for $p>1$ leads to an uncountable (nested) family of invariant subspaces. I.e., instead of bv consider the sequence space
$$
\mathrm{bv}^p = \left\{ (a_n) : \sum_n |a_{n+1}-a_n|^p < \infty \right\}
$$

Comment: Seems like a good idea. How do you show that the $\mathscr E[\mathrm{bv}^p]$ are not equal for two different choices of the parameter $p$?

Comment: @PseudoNeo: Thinking about it a little more, I found a major problem even with the original construction, edited the post to explain it.

Comment: Your answer is great. (I think that your "modification" of the definition must be what McMullen had in mind, even if his message is quite unclear).

Comment: Seems unlikely that I get a better answer between now and in two days. I give you the bounty with pleasure.